# .css() function doesn't set any properties to any elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, html

I've got an issue with a jQuery function: .css()

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="..." id="about">
// OTHER HTML CODE
</div>
```

This is my jQuery Code:

```
(function($, window, document) {

    $(function() {

        var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

        $('#about').css( "margin-top" , viewportHeight );

}(window.jQuery, window, document));
```

I've tried every possible combinations but this isn't working in any way. I've tried every possible synthax of the .css() method with no result.
I've also tried to apply other properties in the .css() func, other method to the $('#about') object as the .click or .fadeOut() when DOM is ready, with no result.

My environment is a project built with Yeomann, Grunt & Angular.js. I'm worried that Angular interferes with the function I'm building, but it seems weird to me because the .click() method on other HTML elements is working (for instance i'm able to .addClass() to elements).

Somebody know this issue?

Comment: Probably just an issue when you entered it, but your JS code is invalid and will throw an error.

Comment: The code in your question would work (other than the syntax issue that Adam referred to). Look in your browser console for errors, double-check that your code doesn't have the typo(s) above, etc.

Comment: Does element exist when code is run? Is it inside an `ng-view` or `ng-include` for example? Have you inspected the live thml to see if changes are being made inline? Please create demo that replicates problem

Comment: @Andrea Giachetto Answered, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for comments it's very likely that jquery can't get the element because the element doesnt exist in that specific moment.

You should use more Angular feature and less Jquery stuff as well.
Anyway one solution can be found using ng-init

```
<div ng-controller="AboutController">
    <div class="..." id="about" ng-init="measure()">
    // OTHER HTML CODE
    </div>
</div>
```

and then inside `AboutController` or any controller that wraps your `about` element you can use any code you prefer, i'll use the plain JS version

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app') //whatever module you're using
        .controller('AboutController', tcController);

        tcController.$inject = ['$scope', '$window'];
        /* @ngInject */
        function tcController($scope, $window) {

            $scope.measure = function() {
                var viewportHeight = $window.height();
                document.querySelector('#about').style.marginTop = viewportHeight + 'px';
            }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a number when you should set a dimension.

```
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
```

Will return a number let's say it returns `42`

But when you set a css property you cannot set just a number, you need to set a dimension like `42px`.

So just try this way:

```
$('#about').css( "margin-top" , viewportHeight + 'px' );
```

This is also why you don't get any JS error, the JS is basically correct, the problem is in the CSS property and when a css property is wrong is just ignored by the browser.

**Vanilla JS**

I don't usually use jQuery so if this doesn't solve the problem I would recommend to let jQuery be and use plain Javascript (easier and faster).

```
document.getElementById('about').style.marginTop = viewportHeight + 'px';
```

Comment: jQuery handles that.

Comment: This is not the case jquery will automatically handle the px if you pass an int value

Comment: @Bolza why would you try to remove angular tag from question when the issue may well be connected to using jQuery on top of angular? Makes it a destructive edit, please be more careful

Comment: dont need to concatenate px

Comment: @charlietfl i thought angular was out of the question scope also because the OP code has no angular code in it... but still you're probably right, is still used as framework so the tag might be meaningful.

Comment: @Bolza it is most likely a big part of the issue. The jQuery code shown should really be converted to angular

Comment: The #about div is in the ng-view directive, and this HTML element exist in the view about.html

Comment: @AndreaGiachetto In this case IT IS very likely that jquery can't get the element because the element doesnt exist in that specific moment.

Comment: @bolza So you're saying that when angular fires its directive (in this case NG-VIEW), jQuery has already inspected the DOM and won't attach any property inside a view that has been loaded by Angular?

Comment: @AndreaGiachetto I would think so, the real reason is that DOM manipulation is meant to be done using a directive and not inside the page controller. Anyway i posted a new answer that i hope will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yo have errors in your Jquery code, the better way to set the height is write the code inside document.ready() method.

fiddled the answer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamshajeer/ehxac8o2/1/)

**html**

```
<div class="..." id="about">
// OTHER HTML CODE
</div>
```

**Script**

```
    $(function() {

        var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

        $('#about').css( "margin-top" , viewportHeight );

    });

/* another better solution
$(document).ready(function(){
        var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

        $('#about').css( "margin-top" , viewportHeight );

})

*/
```

**CSS**

```
#about{
    background:red;
    width:100%;

}
```

hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score -1):

```
 (function($, window, document) {

    $(function() {

        var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

        $('#about').css( "margin-top" , viewportHeight );

}(window.jQuery, window, document));
```

The code is not proper .. This must be giving an error in console.kindly check. 
There are 2 functions and only 1 function has the closing bracker "}". The other inner function is not closing properly.

Well you can try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

        $('#about').css( "margin-top" , viewportHeight );
});
```

Comment: `$(function() {` in OP is the same thing as `$(document).ready(function(){`